# Portability of google workspace service accounts

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-apis-explorer

I am creating an app that uses google calendar api to give additional features to clients. For this I need domain wide writer access to all the calendars of the organization. I could not achieve this using plain OAuth2.0 flow, so I started exploring service accounts.

The problem is, for each domain I need to create a service account for my app. This will be very cumbersome as I cannot ask each client to go and create a service account and grant admin user-access permission every time I pitch my product.

Is there some workaround where I need to create only one service account that is portable across domains, or some convenient way like sharing a URL like we do in 3LO oAuth flow?

Also, is there any alternate to service account itself i.e. how can I get domain wide resource edit priviliege within 3LO oAuth framework?

Answer (score 1):

*The only way to achieve this unfortunately is by creating a service account for each domain you want to be working with and later impersonate the admin.*

The main purpose of a service account is for this account to impersonate another user and to access data on their behalf. Since you need a write access to the calendars of the organization and every domain has a different admin, you will have to impersonate each one of them in order to obtain the permissions you need.

It is also important to note the fact that Calendar API uses OAuth 2.0, hence all the authentication is done using this flow.

#### Reference

- [Understanding Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts).